# JavaScript date and time displaying wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I have a school project I'm doing in a web design class, and I never was good with JavaScript. I put the code in exactly as the book wanted, but it doesn't show up right.

Here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--Hide from old browsers
    var today = new Date()
    var dayofweek = today.toLocaleString()
    dayLocate = dayofweek.indexOf(" ")
    weekDay = dayofweek.substring(0, dayLocate)
    newDay = dayofweek.substring(dayLocate)
    dateLocate = newDay.indexOf(",")
    monthDate = newDay.substring(0, dateLocate+1)
    yearLocate = dayofweek.indexOf("2017")
    year = dayofweek.substr(yearLocate, 4)

    var springDate = new Date("March 21, 2017")
    var daysToGo = springDate.getTime()-today.getTime()
    var daysToSpring = Math.ceil(daysToGo/(1000*60*60*24))

    document.write("<p style='margin-left:10%; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:14'>Today is "+weekDay+" "+monthDate+" "+year+", that leaves only "+daysToSpring+" days until the start of spring.")
    document.write("<br />Spring is the time to prepare your landscape for new growth of flowers and lawns. ")
    document.write("<br /> Call us now at (221) 555-9100 for a free consultation and free estimate.</p>")

    //-->
    </script>
```

It should display the time part as Tuesday, February 07, 2017 but instead shows  2/7/2017, 2017. Help please?

Comment: you can use a library like momentjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: @JuanC. How would I put that in the document.write properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works perfectly.

```js
        var today = new Date();
        var dayofweek = today.toUTCString();
        dayofweek = dayofweek.substring(0,dayofweek.indexOf(':')-3);
    
        var springDate = new Date("March 21, 2017");
        var daysToGo = springDate.getTime()-today.getTime();
        var daysToSpring = Math.ceil(daysToGo/(1000*60*60*24));
    
        document.write("<p style='margin-left:10%; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:14'>Today is "+dayofweek+", that leaves only "+daysToSpring+" days until the start of spring.");
        document.write("<br />Spring is the time to prepare your landscape for new growth of flowers and lawns. ");
        document.write("<br /> Call us now at (221) 555-9100 for a free consultation and free estimate.</p>");
```

Answer (score 2):

[dateObj.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) accepts 2 [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Parameters) where you can set the Date format

```js
    var today = new Date()
    var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
    console.log(today .toLocaleString('en-EN', options));
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js` at the top of your page and then do the following to format your date

`moment(new Date("March 21, 2017")).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY");` // Tuesday, March 21st 2017

Here is the

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

to moment doc for `format`